# WPF ToolTip Trigger Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tooltip

I am implementing [idataerrorinfo](/questions/tagged/idataerrorinfo) in my ViewModel to perform validation on some of my bound properties. I am then trying to use the following to set the [tooltip](/questions/tagged/tooltip) and automatically show it:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip.IsOpen" Value="True"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip.StaysOpen" Value="True"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip.Placement" Value="Bottom"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The problem is that while the [tooltip](/questions/tagged/tooltip) is being set it doesn't appear unless i put my cursor over the input. I would like to show a ToolTip automatically when validation fails.

I can think of many ways to validate data but I'm looking for a solution which is streamlined, easily reusable and doesn't clutter the rest of my code up (and the UI).If there is a better way to do this then Id like to hear about it.

Cheers

Comment: why not use a `Validation.ErrorTemplate` it goes to the Adorned layer and does not affect the general layout. ToolTip's are not very friendly if you have your cursor force show a tooltip for a textbox error when it's actually over a button or elsewhere in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Viv.  I used a style to define a validation.errortemplate for the textbox that is in a style.  It adds a red box under the control with the error message.  You can try this and adjust it.  I don`t think forcing the tooltip is the right idea.   I would use a popup from the validation.errortemplate if you really must have that functionality.

```
<Style x:Key="FTC_ValidateTextBox" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Open Sans Condensed"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="19" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,15,6"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DetailTextBox}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MediumGray}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource MediumRed}" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="parentTextBox" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DetailError}"
                            Text="{Binding AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent, ElementName=parentTextBox}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MediumRed}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MediumRed}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,15,31"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I was using an adorned PopUp but the problem with PopUps is they are always on top. Even when you switch application - don't really like this behavior. I will have a look at your proposal, the reason i thought forcing a ToolTip was a good idea was because of the minimal impact on the rest of the code (clutter).

Comment: How do i wrap the adorned TextBox so that the text doesn't go off the window (since the adorner is on a separate layer)?

Comment: The text is already wrapping as defined in the style. Your just Ned to set a max width for the element in the style setter properties

Comment: I've tried binding to the width of the TextBox so that the TextBlock containing the error scales with it: MaxWidth="{Binding AdornedElement.ActualWidth}"...This doesnt seem to work properly though.

Comment: do you get any binding errors in your output window when you debug your app